# I cloud - AppStore issue

Tags: itunes

My son in US gave his used iPhone to me in India. Even though I set to my id , whenever any AppStore updates prompt come, I am unable to update as it asks for my son's iCloud password, how to resolve

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the apps that your son installed from the App Store (in other words, every app on the phone that’s not a part of iOS) , and then install the apps that you want using your own App Store account.